# My ps3 won't turn on

Tags: ps3

I was playing dc universe online and my tv screen turned different colors and froze then I turned off my PS3 and it wouldn't turn back on.

Comment: Does it still have the red light on in front?  What happens when you try to turn it back on?  Does anything happen?

Comment: When I try to turn it back on it still has the ble and green light but no picture shows on my tv

Answer (score -1):

Please edit your post and describe what happens when you try to turn you PS3 on again.

You can try unplugging it from electricity and let it cool off, then try turning it on again,
try to pay attention to any indication lights that appear on the PS3 or any image that appears on your TV.

Make sure to come back and update if you find a solution to the issue, or if the PS3 turns on again normally, and state what you did to solve the issue